# Ubuntu 20.04 - Постоянно заканчивается свободная память

Tags: ubuntu

На своём ноутбуке для рабочих нужд установил Linux Ubuntu 20.04. При этом у меня уже стоял Windows. И, либо я недостаточно выделил место для Ubuntu при разметке системы, либо что-то в процессе работы пошло не так и у меня ненужными файлами сейчас забита система, но место постоянно заканчивается.

Я читал различные статьи по очистке, теперь я регулярно использую базовые команды для очистки в терминале или программу BleachBit. Но место стало кончатся катастрофически часто. То есть я по 3-5 раз в день вижу надпись "осталось свободно XXX мегабайт" (даже до гига уже не дотягивает). Иногда не могу запустить какую-то программу или даже сам комп, приходится открывать терминал под root-ом и чистить так.

Поэтому прошу накидать ссылок/советов по таким вопросам:

1. Как локализировать причину постоянной забивки памяти?
2. Какие есть удобные способы автоматической очистки памяти?
3. Нужно ли мне смотреть в сторону удаления программ каких-то или стоит выделить под Ubuntu больше ресурсов?

Сейчас по памяти такая картина (постоянно забита папка /dev/nvme0n1p5):

```
max@mLux:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  167M  1,4G  11% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   19G   19G  114M 100% /
tmpfs           7,7G  169M  7,5G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      9,7M  9,7M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/246
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2790
/dev/loop1      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop4       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/discord/156
/dev/loop5       67M   67M     0 100% /snap/cups/980
/dev/loop6      106M  106M     0 100% /snap/core/16091
/dev/loop3      156M  156M     0 100% /snap/chromium/2666
/dev/loop7      155M  155M     0 100% /snap/chromium/2642
/dev/loop8      165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
/dev/loop10      64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2015
/dev/loop9       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/discord/158
/dev/loop12      74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/864
/dev/loop21     167M  167M     0 100% /snap/postman/227
/dev/loop15     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93
/dev/loop11     106M  106M     0 100% /snap/core/16202
/dev/loop13     155M  155M     0 100% /snap/chromium/2655
/dev/loop22      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/959
/dev/loop14     350M  350M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
/dev/loop25      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop18      41M   41M     0 100% /snap/snapd/20092
/dev/loop17     321M  321M     0 100% /snap/vlc/3078
/dev/loop24     410M  410M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/5133
/dev/loop19     497M  497M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
/dev/loop23     167M  167M     0 100% /snap/postman/225
/dev/loop16     408M  408M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/5088
/dev/loop20      41M   41M     0 100% /snap/snapd/20290
/dev/loop26     322M  322M     0 100% /snap/vlc/3721
/dev/nvme0n1p3  381G  140G  242G  37% /windows
/dev/nvme0n1p6   75G   32G   39G  45% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   51M  206M  20% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,6G  4,6M  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Не память, а диск. Смотреть в первую очередь на /var/log

Comment: И собственно, что на этой машине работает? Какой-нибудь сервер?

Comment: `ncdu` в руки и вперёд изучать занятое место

Comment: Ну и 20 гигабайт ощущается как-то маловато (лично мне для работы даже 50 гигабайт не хватает)

Comment: БД поднимал год назад в рамках какого-то учебного курса. Но я не думаю, что это влияет

Comment: Почему же постоянно забивается /dev/nvme0n1p5? И как это исправить?
Пробовал туда зайти через терминал. Пишет, что это не папка.

Comment: `ncdu` в руки и вперёд изучать занятое место — через точку монтирования, а не пытаться тыкаться в блочное устройство напрямую

Comment: Берёшь `Gparted Live` и увеличиваешь раздел, на котором стоит система хотя бы до сотни. Согласен с @andreymal - 20 гигов для десктопного линукса - мало. У тебя там тем более куча снап софта. Забэапиться не забудь на всякий случай.

Answer (score 0):

Временно решил проблему, освободил 3+ гига. Было много старых ядер, удалил их командой из [статьи](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80)